# ansible/jinja2 reject all items from list of dicts with specific attribute

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I have a list of dicts like this:

```
list_of_dicts:
  - name: Item1
  - name: Item2
    type: special
  - name: Item3
  - name: Item4
    type: small
```

As you can see, not all items have a `type` attribute. Context: If no `type` attribute is set, that means the item is of the default type.

I would like to select all items which are NOT of type `special`.

I've tried this: `list_of_dicts | rejectattr('type', 'equalto', 'special')`

Unfortunately, this fails with a `AnsibleUndefinedVariable: 'dict object' has no attribute 'type'` error because some of the items do not have a type.

What is a good way to solve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: I actually didn't pay enough attention to the latest edit of the existing answer from @ranjandas and the following comments. My first solution is almost similar. I guess you are more interested by the second one.

---

Here are 2 different ways to achieve your requirement.

1. The first solution uses only filters available in ansible by default: `rejectattr` you already mentionned and its counterpart `selectattr`. The idea is to add two lists. The first one is made by selecting all dicts not having the `type` atttribute. The second one is made by selecting dict having the `type` attribute and rejecting those where it equals `special`.
2. For the second solution, I used the [`json_query` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#json-query-filter) which requires `pip install jmespath` on the controller. As you can see below it is much more compact.

The choice is yours !

The demo playbook:

```yaml
---
- name: Show not so special items
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    list_of_dicts:
      - name: Item1
      - name: Item2
        type: special
      - name: Item3
      - name: Item4
        type: small

  tasks:
    - name: Use select/rejectattr
      debug:
        msg: >-
          {{
            (list_of_dicts | selectattr('type', 'undefined') | list)
            +
            (list_of_dicts | selectattr('type', 'defined') | rejectattr('type', 'eq', 'special') | list)
          }}

    - name: Use json_query
      vars:
        query: "[?type != 'special']"
      debug:
        msg: "{{ list_of_dicts | json_query(query) | list }}"
```

Which gives:

```
PLAY [Show not so special items] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Use select/rejectattr] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "name": "Item1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Item3"
        },
        {
            "name": "Item4",
            "type": "small"
        }
    ]
}

TASK [Use json_query] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        {
            "name": "Item1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Item3"
        },
        {
            "name": "Item4",
            "type": "small"
        }
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP ********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use `rejectattr` to reject items that has `type` undefined and use `selectattr` to select the items that are `equalto` special.

```
{{ list_of_dicts | rejectattr("type", "undefined") | selectattr("type", "equalto", "special") | list }}
```

edit:

How about combining two lists like given below? I don't know whether this is the best possible way, but it works.

```
{{ list_of_dicts | selectattr("type", "undefined") | list }} + {{ list_of_dicts | rejectattr("type", "undefined") | rejectattr("type", "equalto", "special") | list}}
```

Comment: I wrote in my question: `I would like to select all items which are NOT of type special.`. Your suggestion does the exact opposite, it selects the items which ARE of type special.

Comment: @Zulakis Sorry for that, I missed the key point when posting. I have updated the answer, could you see if that fits the purpose?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure your second suggestion will work. Upvoted. If possible, I would prefer a more concise way of achieving this (instead of combining two filtered lists). So, if you have any other ideas... ;-)